# React Redux Pages With React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently I am looking in to making an application with React and Redux. Now in most examples they use React Router, and I was wondering what this is exactly for.

My application is going to have many pages (at least 20) with dynamic content. Now my question is, could this be made with React Router? I see some things that say it helps you make one page applications, but what is a *one page* application? So basically, would it be best to go with React Router, or another library? Also, even if it is a multi-page application, would I still only have one `index.js` and one `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React router allows you to set "Routes" such as:

```
/
/posts
/posts/12345
/posts/archive
```

Without `react-router`, you will have to manage the changes to the URL yourself.

Additionally, for larger, more complex apps, `react-router` (along with Webpack) will allow you to do 'code splitting', allowing you to serve only the required files for each URL. Without this, your single bundle.js file can become very large.

Comment: So this does support *multi-page* apps?

Comment: You can achieve multiple pages in a single page app with react. React Router allows you far better control over the URL. Code Splitting is where you are separating your production files into smaller chunks, and your users will only access them when they visit the URL where those files are needed. This is important, since javascript apps can become extremely heavy quite quickly. More info: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense! Ok, last question, for instance, I have the pages `home` and `login`. Would they get their own names like `home.js/home.html` and `login.js/login.html`, or are they all still served from `index.js/index.html`?

Comment: Everything is served from the same index.html file. It's the JavaScript where the 'routing' occurs. In a single page app, you never 'actually' change to a new page, the URL is managed to make it appear as though you are.

Comment: Ok, perfect, so even though I am using React Router, it will redirect me to new pages (therefor not *single-page*)?

Comment: single page, with javascript making it appear as though you're visiting a different page. I'd suggest following the tutorial on their GitHub page, it will make things clearer.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think I understand now! So basically it is just re-rendering the page with inline components.

Answer (score 2):

> what is a one page application?

A single page application has all the necessary code retrieved with a single page load.  An example of a SPA is gmail. SPA's don't need to refresh the browser when navigating between views.

> would it be best to go with React Router, or another library?

React Router is not the official routing library from Facebook but it is by far the most popular.  I recommend using it since it has a large community behind it that can help you if you run into any issues.

> would I still only have one index.js and one index.html?

With React you will need something like Webpack to transpile JSX and ES6.  The entry point for your app will be a bundled js file created by Webpack that contains all your javascript code.  You could have multiple entry points, for instance if you wanted to have a separate bundle for your node modules.  So in short, you will have one index.html file but you could have one or multiple js files.